# History of Double Coset Enumeration.

Tags: math-history

I must know how and when it began. I can't seem to find anything historical on this. All I know up to this point is that Todd-Coxeter method was created in 1936. And, "words"? How did they even arise in double coset enumeration? I need more. :)

Comment: The book *Pioneers of Representation Theory: Frobenius, Burnside, Schur, and Brauer* by **Charles Curtis** is an excellent exposition on this subject, at least its first chapters contain some information. http://books.google.com.tw/books?id=MvWJZSxqLZwC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Representations%2Bcharles+curtis&hl=zh-TW&sa=X&ei=TG3IT9KwMoGimQX0maXhDg&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=Representations%2Bcharles%20curtis&f=false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention double coset enumeration. There is some historical comment  in the paper

R. Brown,  N. Ghani, A.Heyworth, C.D.Wensley), `String-rewriting
systems for double coset systems', J. Symb. Comp. 41 (2006)
573-590.

also available from the arXiv . arXiv:math/0508391 .

The following comes from the Introduction:

"The primary alternative to Todd-Coxeter procedures
for ordinary coset enumeration and computation of groups
given by presentations is string rewriting.
In finite settings the two approaches are comparable:
certain problems being more effectively addressed by the enumerative method
and others benefitting more from a rewriting approach.
However, for cases involving infinitely many elements,
rewriting rather than enumeration is the natural choice.

This paper demostrates how string rewriting can be applied to the problems
of computing double cosets, giving a new alternative to the
Todd-Coxeter methods which can further be applied to infinite groups."